# Javascript wrap every Hebrew word from a string in span tags excluding punctuation

Tags: javascript, html

Title says it all. I have a string:

וחזקת והיית לאיש1, הנה ידוע2 שהמאמר שאמר אדמו"ר (מהורש"ב) נ"ע ביום השביעי3 דחגיגת הבר מצוה של בנו יחידו כ"ק מו"ח אדמו"ר, י"ט תמוז4 תרנ"ג [שמאמר זה הוא סיום וחותם ההמשך תפילין דמארי עלמא5 שהתחיל לומר בי"ב תמוז, יום הבר מצוה] היתה התחלתו בפסוק זה. – השייכות דפסוק זה (וחזקת והיית לאיש) לבר מצוה בפשטות היא, ע"פ הידוע6 דזה שבן שלש עשרה (דוקא) מחוייב במצוות הוא כי אז דוקא נק' בשם איש. וצריך להבין, דמכיון שבן י"ג שנה נעשה איש (ע"פ טבע), מהי ההדגשה לומר (בחגיגת בר מצוה) וחזקת והיית לאיש. וגם צריך להבין, הרי המעלה דבן י"ג שנה היא שאז נעשה בר דעת7, דדעת הוא במוחין, ובפרט לפי המבואר בהמאמר ד"ה איתא במדרש תילים תרנ"ג [שהוא אחד המאמרים שחזר אותם כ"ק מו"ח אדמו"ר בחגיגת הבר  שלו]8 שהמעלה דבן י"ג שנה היא שאז יש לו עצם המוחין9, ומהו הדיוק בבן י"ג שנה בהתואר איש שמורה10 על המדות

As you can see, it's in Hebrew with various commas and brackets etc. I want the user to be able to click on an individual word and stuff happens etc. 
I'm able to wrap every word in span tags with string.split(" ") and then just loop through it and add the span tags to every word, but then it keeps the commas and other punctuation, which is a no-no.

I tried to use a regex to replace all of the punctuation and wrap the remaining result only around the span tags (since regex doesn't directly support Hebrew), like this : Html.replace(/[^.,/#!$%\^&*;:{}=-_`~()[]\–]/g,"$&"); but I'm not so good with regex and that actually ends up wrapping every **character** (besides the punctuation) in spans, but I want every full word.

There's probably something simple in regex I'm missing, but not sure what it is. 
I don't want to use any external libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making the assumption that it is also okay to remove numbers with the punctuation.

You are correct to split on whitespace. From there you can remove non Hebrew characters with a simple regular expression. Example:

```
var str = `שנה היא שאז נעשה בר דעת7, דדעת הוא במוחין, ובפרט לפי המבואר בהמאמר ד`;

var words = str.split(" ");

for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  words[i] = words[i].replace(/[\x1E-\x7F]/g, '')
}

// words is now an array of words only containing Hebrew characters.
```

The regular expression covers characters in the range 30-127. You can change the range you want by changing `\x1E` and/or `\x7F` to some other hex number. [Here is a reference.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block))

The reason that the replace isn't done before the split is because the regular expression will replace spaces.